# Can you save memory within VS to use in another run?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a very long (over 3 hour, and somewhat manual) pre-processing method to obtain all the data I need to run an analysis.  I am running this in debug mode and the pre-processing works great and I get all the data I want correctly, however once I start processing the data, I discover a bug.  If I stop the process I will have to re-run the pre-processing again, only to discover another possible bug.  Is there a way to save this pre-processed data, so I can just dump it into memory without having to pre-process everytime without stopping the process?

I am break pointed just after the pre-process and before the processing, and would kind of like a save point without having to STOP the process and add code.

Comment: What kind of data? Can it be stored in DB or local file?

Comment: You need to save the data without adding any code? You mean you are looking for a feature in VS to do this for you?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter I would like it to be stored locally somehow, hopefully in VS as kaptan suggests .... I dont have database set up. Its my classes I have created, and its very OOP so it gets deep with interfaces and extends.  I was hoping there was a quick solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data takes long to generate, but there's not actually that much of it, then you could use serialization to write your data into a file.

Probably the simplest option would be to use `BinaryFormatter`: you just need to mark all the types that you want to save as `[Serializable]` and it will work automatically.

Comment: Yea, this is the best solution I have found as well.  I just have to go through ALL my classes to add the [Serializable] tags (hoping I didn't miss something), and then the lengthy 3 hour process again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your requirement but how about creating a memory dump file? Then you can continue execution as many times as you want from a known save point. See on MSDN: [Use Dump Files to Debug App Crashes and Hangs in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5zhxt22.aspx#BKMK_Create_a_dump_file).